# Martial ui react js how to align griditem to center

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

how can i align center this input field in my form. using material-ui to create this field all my fields are currently aligned to the left of the form.

```
 <GridItem xs={2}>
        <CustomInput
          labelText="Children Count"
          formControlProps={{
            fullWidth: true,
          }}
          inputProps={{
            type: 'text',
            ...formik.getFieldProps(
              'family.relationCountsConfig.childrenCount',
            ),
            error:
              get(
                touched,
                'family.relationCountsConfig.childrenCount',
                '',
              ) &&
              get(errors, 'family.relationCountsConfig.childrenCount', ''),
          }}
        />
```

Comment: you can put parent div with property margin :"0 auto"

Comment: have multiple fields with same component. i need to make this field aligned center from the rest

Comment: can you provide more information about what you did ?

Comment: i have created a form with multiple fields called spouse count, children count, sibling count and father count. all these fields fill up at the left of the form i need to move the children count field to the center of the form apart form the rest

Comment: hi i figured it out have to put <Grid container spacing={0} alignItems="center" justify="center"> in the griditem wrapper

Comment: okay great @user32131